# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in scriptlet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g

I have this code in a scriptlet to connect to a Oracle 11g database. This sits in a asp and will return data from the database (Please ignore the fact scriptlets are used and MVC pattern has been ignored, I can't do anything about this) When I try to connect to the database and run a query I get this error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Could someone please review the code and see what I am doing wrong? Many Thanks

```
Driver myDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
DriverManager.registerDriver(myDriver);

Connection conn = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
String DBURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:aaa";
String DBUSER = "user";
String DBPASSWORD = "password";
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
sql.append("select 'aa', count(*) from queue where priority <= 3 ");
sql.append("union ");
sql.append("select 'bb', count(*) from queue where priority = 4 ");
sql.append("union ");
sql.append("select 'cc', count(*) from ccrqueue ");
sql.append("union ");
sql.append("select 'dd', count(*) from ddqueue ");
sql.append("union ");
sql.append("select 'ee', count(*) from eequeue ");
sql.append("union "); 
sql.append("select 'ff', count(*) from ffqueue ");
sql.append("union ");
sql.append("select 'gg', count(*) from ggqueue where id is null ");
sql.append("union ");
sql.append("select 'hh', count(*) from hhqueue" );
sql.append("union" );
sql.append("select 'ii', count(*) from iiqueue" );
sql.append("union" );
sql.append("select 'jj', count(*) from jjqueue where queuetype = ERROR" );
sql.append("union" );
sql.append("select 'kk', count(*) from kkqueue" );
sql.append("order by 2 desc" );

try {
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);
statement = conn.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql.toString());
out.println(resultSet);

} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
    if (conn != null) {
               conn.close();
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: I see two problems: `queuetype = ERROR` is missing single quotes. I guess it should be `'ERROR'` and there is a whitespace missing in front of the `order by`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lines that need a blank space. For example:

```
sql.append("union" );
sql.append("select 'ii', count(*) from iiqueue" );
```

will result: `unionselect 'ii', count(*) from iiqueue`

thal will generate an ORA-00933